Why is a group of North Carolina women (apparently) traveling to every Trump rally?
I saw this article recently in The Independent:

“Somebody said, ‘Women don’t like Donald Trump,’” he [Trump] said from a rally
in Johnstown, Pennsylvania on August 30. “I said, ‘I think that’s
wrong. I think they love me.’ I love them.”
He pointed to a group of women from North Carolina who have traveled
to 227 rallies.
“They’re wealthy as hell. Look at them. They’ve got nothing but cash,”
he added. “Their husbands are great. But they allow them to go all
over the country.

You can find this moment starting from 42:08 in the official Johnstown rally video. There’s also a photo of these women available from Getty Images.

What's the deal with these women following Trump to so many rallies? Are they just super-fans, big-money donors, or is there some political game plan going on here?

Why are they all from North Carolina? Did Trump's team pick them on purpose, or is it just a random coincidence that this group of super-fans all come from the same state?


Update: the NYT has answered my question now.

Didn't VTC this, but it seems a marginal topic. There's like five of them in the image, so it's not a group that's too large to simply be friends etc.

Maybe Kamala Harris has a group of men from California to travel to all her rallies too. (Not sure if this would be a bit creepy though.) But I fail to see the connection to politics. Much more likely would be rather normal, non-political reasons. Or if there is a political message somewhere, it's really well hidden.

I am voting to reopen this question because The New York Times recently published an article revealing that this group of women are all from a single church, so there is actually a reason behind this.

It can be anything. About half of the USA votes Trump.

There's no accounting for human behavior.
Seems like a clique of super-fans that bonded.
No "facts" to offer in explanation.

https://archive.is/Uz9mC answers the question

Well, if we're gonna have guess- or generalization-based answers, based on your quote they do fit a certain pattern:

“Those most enthralled with Donald Trump were not at the very bottom — the illiterate, the hungry,” she writes. Rather, Trump’s biggest fans could be found among “the elite of the left-behind,” meaning people “who were doing well within a region that was not.”

North Carolina ranks 39th out of 50 on average household income as I'm writing this, i.e. based on 2021 data. And I'm assuming Trump's characterization of those five women being "wealthy as hell" is correct. (There isn't really any press coverage that I can use cross check the wealth claims, alas. The topic of that group appears to be too obscure for the press, at the moment.)

That research is undoubtedly true, but the presentation is limited. It obscures the fact that the differences were small and that all groups of White voters were at least equally likely to vote for Trump, unlike Black voters and most other voters of color. But, basically, the "locally rich, nationally poor" group voted for Trump at a 65% rate, while the "locally poor, nationally poor" group voted for Trump at a 58% rate. Significant? Probably, but they differ by fewer than 10 percentage points and are both still majority pro-Trump (and not overwhelmingly pro-Trump, either).

That makes little intuitive sense.  The elite of a poor region is by definition a small slice of its population.  That elite might very well overwhelmingly vote for Trump, but Trump would not be winning those states if he did not have a broader support.  Which he is well-documented as having from non-college whites, presumably not the regional elite.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica - The assertion is essentially that a low position relative to national income positively influences the likelihood of voting for Trump, but a low position relative to local income negatively influences it. This appears to be true as far as it goes, but the local income effect is a small correction to racial and national income effects.

@Obie2.0 Oh, I know what the assertion is.  The maths of it is what I find issue with.
